# Datetime picker cannot be installed on angularjs 1.2.16

Tags: angularjs, bower

I am having trouble installing a datetime picker on angularjs using bower install.
I am using this library: https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker but for some reason it does not seem to be installed and the error says:
 **ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular**

My bower.json looks as below:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.16",
    "json3": "~3.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~3.1.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.16",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.16",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.16",
    "angular-animate": "1.2.16",
    "angular-touch": "1.2.16",
    "angular-route": "1.2.16",
    "font-awesome": "4.3.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.12.0",
    "oclazyload": "~0.5.2",
    "angular-loading-bar": "~0.7.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.13",
    "angular-toggle-switch": "~1.2.1",
    "metisMenu": "~1.1.3",
    "angular-chart.js": "~0.5.2",
    "satellizer": "~0.13.1",
    "angular-payments": "*",
    "angular-file-upload": "~2.2.0",
    "bootstrap-select": "~1.9.3",
    "ngBootbox": "~0.1.3",
    "angular-ui-tinymce": "~0.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.16",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.16"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "^1.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.16"
  },
  "appPath": "app"
}
```

It works on my local machine if I add this parameter when using bower install --force-latest ... but this is not working on my production where I use Heroku for deploying

Comment: angular 1.2.16 very old.  The plugin you posted was designed for `angular-ui bootstrap Version: 1.2.0 - 2016-04-07`.  according to http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/, the last version that supported angular 1.2.x was  `angular-ui bootstrap 0.12.0 - Nov 16 2014`.  This plugin isn't compatible with that version of angular.

Comment: @Claies thanx for the informations, this is very helpful, do u by any chance know any compatible datetime picker module for my angularjs version? If there is not, what would you suggest me to do in this case?

Comment: @Claies it worked with bower install --force-latest, is there anyway I could do the same on my production with heroku?

Comment: don't use angular 1.2.x unless you have absolutely no other choice.  it is ancient, many things don't work or have issues, and the updates to angular up through 1.5 have improved performance, as well as updated syntax.

Comment: --force-latest is going to force install the newer version of angular, which may fix issues for this plugin but cause issues for other parts of your app.  you are better off actually designing for the latest release than trying to force anything.

Comment: @Claies are you saying its better for me to upgrade the angularjs version? if so, do you think it would make lots of trouble for me to fix depended modules?

Comment: also, is there any datetime picker for this particular version, I would rather stay on this version better than screw up other things just for this feature to install

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there were datepicker modules available for that angular version two years ago, but I don't really know anymore where you would find them;  I would probably start with looking at what modules are compatible with that specific ui-bootstrap version 0.12.0;  I think it had a datepicker.  for the record, discussing module availability is really off topic here.

Comment: @Claies I found a particular version of datetimepicker here https://www.versioneye.com/javascript/zhaber:angular-ui-bootstrap-datetimepicker/0.12.0 but it does not seem working this one either, eventhou its 0.12.0....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861497/2393789